# Network Discovery using Snmp in java(using Pim)

Tags: java

I am new to networking java not sure about snmp polling etc.According  I need to build the java application on below requirement anyone please give me an idea to start or anycode to refer similar to this.

The requirement follows like this:

1)To implement multicast network discovery using snmp in java

2)Create CompletedRouterList (initially NULL) to store the routers for which discovery was complete and a PendingRouterList containing the routers for which discover is pending.

3)At initialization time, statically populate the PendingRouterList with initial set of routers from some config file.

4)For each router in the PendingRouterList, if multicast is enabled then query the pimInterfaceTable to obtain the list of 
interfaces on which PIM is enabled. For example if R1 has PIM enabled and has interfaces 1/1 and 1/2/ on which PIM
is enabled then we will have:-

```
            1/2         1/1
      --------- R1 ----------
```

5)For each router that has at least 1 interface that has PIM enabled on it, query it’s PIM Neighbor table to obtain the list of 
it’s PIM neighbors. PIM neighbor table also gives the interface index with which the router is connected with it’s neighbor.
This information can be used to build the link between the router and neighbor(s).

For example if R1 has neighbors R2 connected to 1/1 and R3 connected to 1 / 2 then we can build the table as:-

```
                     1/2     1/1
         R3----------R1 ---------- R2
```

Please help in coding this,i need to know how to start and what are the jar files required etc.

I just need an idea to start with or any application to look up and start with.

Comment: Any help please thanks in advance